# Вывод телефона по маске

Tags: yii2

Подскажите, как сделать вывод телефона в читабельном виде?

В базе хранится в виде 1234567890, а нужно вывести пользователю - (123) 456-78-90.

Городить огород не хочется, явно есть уже готовые решения.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно поможет функция для форматирования номеров телефонов по нескольким маскам https://dotzero.blog/php-phone-format/

```
function phone_format($phone, $format, $mask = '#')
{
$phone = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $phone);

if (is_array($format)) {
    if (array_key_exists(strlen($phone), $format)) {
        $format = $format[strlen($phone)];
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

$pattern = '/' . str_repeat('([0-9])?', substr_count($format, $mask)) . '(.*)/';

$format = preg_replace_callback(
    str_replace('#', $mask, '/([#])/'),
    function () use (&$counter) {
        return '${' . (++$counter) . '}';
    },
    $format
);

return ($phone) ? trim(preg_replace($pattern, $format, $phone, 1)) : false;
}
```

Пример

```
$phones = array(
    '926 111-2233',
    '9261112233',
    '8 (926) 111 22 33',
    '8 926 111-22-33',
    '559-8833',
    '5598833',
    '',
    'qweqwe'
);

$formats = array(
    '7' => '###-##-##',
    '10' => '+7 (###) ### ####',
    '11' => '# (###) ### ####'
);

foreach ($phones AS $phone) {
    echo phone_format($phone, $formats, '#');
}
```